# Add new column and alter existing column in single alter statement in ms-sql

Tags: sql-server

I have tried this but no luck.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.account
    ADD [createdBy] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [createdDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
        [modifiedBy] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [modifiedDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
    ALTER COLUMN [alias] [NVARCHAR] (MAX) NOT NULL
```

Please, anyone, help me?

Comment: `ADD` and `ALTER COLUMN` need to be 2 separate DDL statements.

Comment: @Larnu any specific reason?

Comment: Because that's how the syntax was designed.